# stop play music on dismiss Modal View Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, modalviewcontroller

dear
i need a little help here.
i have to views in my project. (view1 and view2). from view1 i can navigate to view2 and i can go back form view2 to view1.
view2 have w back ground music 
the problem is when the i go back from view2 to view1 the music still play.

to navigate from view1 to view2

> [self presentModalViewController:view2 animated:YES];

to return to view1

> [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

ii need to make music play when i lunch view2 and stop when return to view1

note:  there is any function to teel application that we have navigate to view1  or view2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement these methods in view2 (that I assume is a view controller).

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

And start the music.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

And stop the music.